# C++ compile time array size from template function

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm not sure why the array creation in the function passes but not the one in the class even though array size is a compile time computable value.

```
template<int N>
int getPow()
{
     int power = 1;
     while(power < N)
         power <<= 1;
     return power;
}

template<int N>
class Test
{
    private:
        int data[getPow<N>()];
};

void testfun()
{
    int test[getPow<2>()]; // passes
    Test<10> t1; // Fails????
}
```

Comment: What are you actually expecting `power <<= 1;` to do` Also that's not a `constexpr`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am pretty sure OP is expecting the value to shift by 1 :), like  sum += 1

Comment: You have an easily fixable incorrect birwise shift operator, and in order to use result of this function as a size of array, you need to mark function `constexpr`.

Comment: You need to throw a `constexpr` in there to commit that  it is, in fact, a compile-time value.

Comment: 0

Compiler does not allow that:

"fields must have a constant size: 'variable length array in structure' extension will never be supported"

Answer (score 5):

As `getPow` is not `constexpr`, it cannot be used in places which require constant expression (as C-array size).

`int test[getPow<2>()]; // passes`
. You unfortunately use VLA extension. It should not pass.

You might solve your issue with:

```
template <unsigned N>
constexpr unsigned getPow()
{
     return 1 << N;
}
```